# How to add css design into Rails render

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to add css design of tooltip into the code below.

```
<%= render 'chat', { chat_title: '**title**', allow_comment: true }%>
```

and the css design of tooltip code is as below.

```
<a class="tooltipped quest-hover" data-position="top" data-tooltip="<%= I18n.t('foo.bar') %>">ℹ️</a>
```

In order to make that pop-up words show while pointing icon ℹ️.
I have tried to put the code as below and the icon goes beneath the title.

```
<span class="quest-subtitle"> title <a class="tooltipped quest-hover" data-position="top" data-tooltip="<%= I18n.t('foo.bar') %>", allow_comment: true>ℹ️</a></span>
```

Is it possible to put a css design class into render?
Thanks.

Comment: yes it's possible! are you having a problem? If so, please describe the problem you're seeing and we can help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you want CSS styles to be applied to the HTML inside the `chat` partial, then you need to include the stylesheet in the `chat` partial or the parent html.erb file. What is your Rails version and are you using Asset pipeline or Webpack?